# Mathematical induction for particular formula.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation

I'm currently learning mathematical induction, but I'm not sure how to start a proof for this formula(the problem is different than what I've been practicing with). I'm not looking for the whole solution I'm just stumped on how to structure the proof for the following formula: $a_n = 3\cdot 2^n-1$, for all integers $n \geq 1$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You've defined a sequence $a_n$; what do you want to prove about it?

Comment: @CarlHeckman the first step to the question was to determine a formula for the sequence: 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96. I did that, but then it asks to prove the formula through induction. I'm not sure how to structure that though

Comment: What do they mean by 'prove the formula'?

Comment: If that's what the exact wording was, then your task is impossible. There are infinitely many sequences that start off with $3,6,12,24,48,96$. Did the question have any other details? (Also, you're missing some parentheses in your formula.)

Comment: ^ Agreed, and that is reason I've never liked these kinds of questions: There are many answers consistent with the given information. For instance, I could give you a polynomial that gives those same 6 numbers as the first 6 terms, but it would not agree with the exponential you've given beyond that.

Comment: its a sequence of the form a1, a2, a3, ... where  n ≥ 1 and the first terms are the numbers that I mentioned above. After I figured out the formula above, it asks me to prove it. I havent seen a question like this before so I don't know how to go about proving that.

Comment: All you can do is show that your formula works for $n=1$, $n=2$, etc., up to $n=6$. You don't need induction for that. (And your formula is wrong; the exponent should be $n-1$, not $n$.)

Comment: Another formula that works is $${1\over40}\,{x}^{5}-{1\over4}\,{x}^{4}+{{11}\over{8}}\,{x}^{3}-{11\over4}\,{x}^{2}+{
{23}\over{5}}\,x.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Quote from a comment:

> the first step to the question was to determine a formula for the sequence: 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96. I did that, but then it asks to prove the formula through induction.

The stated formula, $a_n = 3\cdot 2^n-1$, is incorrect: If $n=1$ then $3\cdot2^n-1 = 3\cdot2-1 = 6 - 1 = 5$, and $5$ is not the first number in the sequence.

However, $a_n = 3\cdot 2^{n-1}$ is correct, for $n=1$ through $6$.

You can prove that simply by computing all six numbers.  Induction usually involves proving an infinite sequence of statement.  I don't know if I've ever seen it used for a finite sequence.  However, in order to prove this by induction, you would need some rule that the sequence is known to follow other than the one you're trying to prove is right, and the only one available is the one you're trying to prove is right.  So this cannot be done by induction, but it can be done by checking the six cases.

Answer (score 0):

A proof usually starts with some statement that is to be proven. In your case, you need more information about how the sequence of $a_n$ is defined. For example:

Let $a_0:=2$ and $a_1:=5$, and for integers $n\ge2$ define $$a_n:=3\cdot a_{n-1}-2\cdot a_{n-2}$$ recursively. Prove that $a_n=3\cdot2^n-1$ for all $n\ge0$.

For this, you would verify the first $2$ cases, indeed $a_0=3\cdot2^0-1=2$ and $a_1=3\cdot2^1-1=5$. Then, assume that the statement s true for $n$ and $n-1$, so
$$
a_n=3\cdot2^n-1 \text{ and } a_{n-1}=3\cdot2^{n-1}-1
$$
Then you need to use the recursive definition to show that also $a_{n+1}=3\cdot2^{n+1}-1$, and indeed:
$$\begin{align}
a_{n+1}&=3\cdot a_n-2\cdot a_{n-1}\\
&=3\cdot(3\cdot2^n-1)-2\cdot(3\cdot2^{n-1}-1)\\
&=3\cdot3\cdot2^n-3-2\cdot3\cdot2^{n-1}+2\\
&=3\cdot3\cdot2^n-1\cdot3\cdot2^n-1\\
&=(3-1)\cdot3\cdot2^n-1\\
&=3\cdot2^{n+1}-1
\end{align}$$

**Oh...**

In case you know that $b_1=3$ and $b_n=2\cdot b_{n-1}$ for $n\ge2$, you can prove that for all $n\ge1$: $b_n=3\cdot2^{n-1}$.

Again, verify that the formula is correct for $n=1$ and see that indeed $3\cdot2^{1-1}=3\cdot1=3=b_1$.

Then, assume that $b_n=3\cdot2^{n-1}$ and show that $b_{n+1}=3\cdot2^n$ using the recursive definition:
$$
b_{n+1}=2\cdot b_n=2\cdot(3\cdot2^{n-1})=3\cdot2\cdot2^{n-1}=3\cdot2^{n}
$$